# Embed the Javasceipr code in Wordpress Not Work

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to embed this code in the WordPress site:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+8)').addClass('active');

$('#songs-load').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();  
 var $rows = $('.songs-table tr');
 var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter('.active:last').index();
 $rows.filter(':lt(' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + ')').addClass('active');
 });

$('#album-load').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
  var $rows = $('.album-table tr');
  var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter('.active:last').index();
  $rows.filter(':lt(' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

I tried to do it like this - wrap the code in script tags:

```
<script>$('table tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+8)').addClass('active');

$('#songs-load').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();  
  var $rows = $('.songs-table tr');
 var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter('.active:last').index();
 $rows.filter(':lt(' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + ')').addClass('active');
 });

$('#album-load').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();  
 var $rows = $('.album-table tr');
var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter('.active:last').index();
 $rows.filter(':lt(' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + ')').addClass('active');
  });
  </script>
```

**BUT It does not work and I guess it should be done another way. Can anyone write me how to embed this code so that it will work in WordPress?**

Comment: It's possible to execute your JavaScript code by wrapping it with `script` tag. However first of all your should verify that this code is included in your WP theme properly. Then check your browser console to be sure there is no errors with your code. Also I would recommend to wrap your JavaScript code, which uses jQuery, with `$(function() { /* your code here */ });` - read more here https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I tried to do it as you mentioned, it still does not work

Comment: I guess, you should provide more debug info to get help.